# How to typeset this symbol?

Tags: symbols

[image: symbol i would like to typeset]

It's not `\mathscr{I}`, which is more italic (slanted)

Comment: This looks like a problem for [detxify!](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: @Seamus: It would be really create if detexify would accept an image URL as input. It's sometimes difficult to draw them correctly.

Comment: @Martin  yeah I've been trying to draw that for like 3 minutes now! My rollerball mouse is not designed for drawing...

Comment: @Seamus: My attempts with a graphics tablet didn't work either.  Does detexify do fonts?

Comment: @Andrew well, it eventually came up with the `mathscr` version for me. But I don't know if it has other maths script fonts...

Comment: I've found something fairly similar in the STIX fonts, but it is more slanted than that and as you specifically say that `\mathscr{I}` is more slanted then I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: I got `\mathscr{I}` as well from detexify. (It's a bit easier to scribble if you have a trackpad instead of a mouse.)

Comment: I had a look at the list, but couldn't find it. Guess it is perhaps not a LaTeX letter.

Comment: @seamus I was about to post a similar question, but detxify answered it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pdfmapfile{+rsfso.map}
\DeclareSymbolFont{rsfso}{U}{rsfso}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{rsfso}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{I}$
\end{document}
```

The `\pdfmapfile` is necessary as of today, since it seems that the map file doesn't correctly register into TeX Live. Works with TeX Live 2010 and 2011/testing.

[image]

The package **mathrsfs** defines `\mathscr` to use the font `rsfs10` (or another size), while my definition requests the font `rsfso10` (or at different size). This font has been developed by Michael Sharpe (`texdoc rsfso`), but his package redefines `\mathcal` instead of using a different command. So I copied the definition from **mathrsfs** changing `rsfs` in the font names into `rsfso`.

The font is just like RSFS, but less slanted. I don't know why the TeX Live manager doesn't add the map file to `pdftex.map`; but since the trick with `\pdfmapline` works, why bother?

Well, we should bother if the engine used is Xe(La)TeX, so a bug report will be filed.

Comment: That appears to be it.. Could you explain the difference with the results that I (and Herbert) got when using \mathscr{I}?

Comment: Works for me now without the pdfmapfile, so apparently the bug got fixed.

Comment: @BenCrowell I guess so.

Answer (score 7):

The sensible answer is "find a suitable font" (for example, the STIX script I is pretty close, but is perhaps too slanted).  Here's a silly answer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
\calligraphy[copperplate,red,heavy,heavy line width=.2cm,light line width=.1cm]
 (0.8,0.51) .. controls +(-.1,-.08) and +(0,-.15) .. (0.5,0.6) .. controls +(0,.15) and +(-.13,-.07) .. (0.85,0.72) +(0,0) .. controls +(-.26,-0.07) and +(.12,.15) .. (0.61,0.3) .. controls +(-.12,-.15) and +(0,-.13) .. (.22,.28);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: script J]

Apart from the blob at the end, it's pretty close.  I know that it's close because I did it by blowing up the image in the post and drawing on top of it.  The line widths probably need tweaking a little, but it's only meant to be a silly answer ...

Comment: NICE! However, I need to use this in a journal article, and I'm not sure if editor's like this stuff..

Comment: You should probably mention that the calligraphy package isn't on CTAN yet and explain where to get it and how awesome it is

Comment: @willem: I did say it was silly!  egreg's answer looks more promising.  I have to say that I'm curious as to why `\mathscr{I}` wouldn't be acceptable to you.

Comment: @Seamus: I was counting on the fact that no-one would be silly enough to actually try to do this.

Comment: The `calligraphy` package is now on CTAN, as a part of package [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3?lang=en). May this info help those new readers of this answer, like me.

Answer (score 3):

Choose another font if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\mathfrak{I}
\mathscr{I}$

\end{document}
```

[image]